# React pdf js - Warning: Setting up fake worker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, pdf.js

I am using a [react pdf viewer](https://react-pdf-viewer.dev/docs/basic-usage/) and I would like to set up worker locally. I have tried doing that like this:

```
import pdfjsWorker from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry";

<Worker workerUrl={pdfjsWorker}>
    <Viewer
      fileUrl={url}
      defaultScale={SpecialZoomLevel.PageFit}
      plugins={[
        defaultLayoutPluginInstance
      ]}
    />
  </Worker>
```

But, that throws a warning:

> Warning: Setting up fake worker

What is the correct way of import a worker then, why do I get this warning?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar issues resolved them by adding the pdf.worker.js

[Git Refrence](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/issues/321)

I added the js file in the head for the worker.js i.e  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.10.377/pdf.worker.js

Then I correct the version (2.10.377 to 2.3.200) as per the console error and it starts loading the pdf
[image: Console error after adding the worker.js]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, instead of write the code like this:

```
<script src="/js/pdf.worker.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/pdf.min.js"></script>
```

I wrote it as:

```
<!--script src="/js/pdf.worker.min.js"></script--> // removed
<script src="/js/pdf.min.js"></script>

$(function() {
  pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '/js/pdf.worker.min.js';    
});
```

Which made the warning disappear ...
even though my PDF was rendered anyway - i just wanted that warning removed.

Comment: Which version? I added the same code using the version 2.14.305 and still having the same error

Comment: `/js/pdf.min.js` is `Version 2.13.148` ( i uploaded it for you here: https://www.filemail.com/d/akbmlpnrqzosgtw )  but i'm migrating the code now to python's `reportlab` module, which is much much much better approach to me. i render the pdf as `A4` and I don't need to guess the dimensions of the screen etc.. everything just works out natively and also you have much more control over the components inside the PDF. because with pdf.min.js when I created a "space" between the image & rendering components in each screen the "space" was rended differently (height&width) - it has no consistency ..

Comment: I'm using only javascript in a .NET mvc project, not a react app

Comment: This is not react, it's native javascript with python behind it ... but ok then, i hope my file attachment will be helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

Watch out!

pdfjs version must be the same

Use it like below please

```
import { Worker, Viewer } from '@react-pdf-viewer/core';
import '@react-pdf-viewer/core/lib/styles/index.css';

import { pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';

const YourComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Worker workerUrl={`https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjs.version}/build/pdf.worker.min.js`}>
        <Viewer fileUrl={fileUrl} />
      </Worker>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/3.0.279/pdf.worker.min.js'
```

Add this after you import `pdfjs-dist` and try matching the version(here 3.0.279) as per the console error. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing the following code in next.js and it works!

```
import "./index.css";

import * as PDFJS from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf";
import * as PDFJSWorker from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker";

export default async function ReaderScreen(props: { filepath: string }) {
  PDFJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = PDFJSWorker;

  const pdf = await PDFJS.getDocument(props.filepath).promise;
  const pages = pdf["_pdfInfo"].numPages;

  return <div>Pages: {pages}</div>;
}
```

If, you see the following error in your code:

[image: Typings Error]

Then, create a `index.d.ts` file in `typings` directory and write the following code:

```
declare module "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf";
declare module "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker";
```

And it should be works now.

Comment: Thanks hey. This also works for vue.js

Answer (score 0):

Worker component expects a `workerUrl` which is of type `string`. You might have to replace `pdfjsWorker` in your code with actual pdf-worker url.

```
const pdfVersion = "2.6.347"
const pdfWorkerUrl = `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfVersion}/pdf.worker.js`
<Worker workerUrl={pdfWorkerUrl}>
    <Viewer
      fileUrl={url}
      defaultScale={SpecialZoomLevel.PageFit}
      plugins={[
        defaultLayoutPluginInstance
      ]}
    />
</Worker>
```

**Note:** Please make sure to set the same version for both pdfjs-dist and worker.

The official documentation mentions the same thing here: https://react-pdf-viewer.dev/docs/basic-usage/