# Getting error when displaying a PDF file using react-pdf

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-pdf, react-pdf-viewer

I integrated the file uploader from the base UI and tried to display the uploaded file using react-pdf package.
I tried converting the file as Blob and then uploaded it with the below code

```
const test = new Blob([file], { type: "application/pdf" });
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(test);
```

Instead, I tried directly assigning the uploaded file to the Document tag but getting that file prop is accepting string instead received file type.

I tried using the file reader also but was unable to achieve it

Below is my code sandbox link:-
https://codesandbox.io/s/base-web-file-uploader-basic-usage-forked-z8zpkr?file=/src/example.js:1712-1820

can anyone please help me in getting this issue resolved

And one more thing which i noticed is in the onLoadError prop was getting the below err

```
Error: Setting up fake worker failed: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'WorkerMessageHandler'
```

Comment: You have to add cdn for the worker...   it would help u... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65955980/react-pdf-js-warning-setting-up-fake-worker     this issue was also closed on github..   https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/issues/321

Comment: I added the cdn now i am getting a different error
 at BaseExceptionClosure (https://hg4tyy.csb.app/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js:1937:29)

    at Object.eval (https://hg4tyy.csb.app/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js:1940:2)

    at __w_pdfjs_require__ (https://hg4tyy.csb.app/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js:27761:42)

I updated the sandbox  also 
https://codesandbox.io/s/base-web-file-uploader-basic-usage-forked-z8zpkr?file=/src/example.js

Comment: Got the issure resolved .
Sandbox link:-https://codesandbox.io/s/base-web-file-uploader-basic-usage-forked-lxsi01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import the library from an alternetive folder, and add pdf worker using cdn:

```
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack';
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjs.version}/legacy/build/pdf.worker.min.js`;
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

1. Copy `node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js` to `public/pdf.worker.js`
2. `options={{workerSrc: "pdf.worker.js"}}` Add this props inside the Document component from react-pdf